# Slice a C#-Hashset

Tags: c#, arrays, hashset, slice

I have a big C# Hashset and I am not able to process it all at once. I need to extract chunks having a given size. I know I can iterate through the hash and copy each element into an array/list that can be later on processed, but is there any faster/more elegant way to do that? Something like a single line?

```
    public static IEnumerable<T[]> Slice<T>(this HashSet<T> h, int size)
    {
        if (0 >= size)
        {
            throw new Exception("0 or negative slice sizes are not accepted!");
        }

        if (null == h || 0 == h.Count)
        {
            yield return new T[0];
            yield break;
        }

        if (size >= h.Count)
        {
            yield return h.ToArray();
            yield break;
        }

        List<T> to_ret = new List<T>(size);
        foreach (T elem in h)
        {
            if (size == to_ret.Count)
            {
                yield return to_ret.ToArray();
                to_ret.Clear();
            }

            to_ret.Add(elem);
        }

        if (0 < to_ret.Count)
        {
            yield return to_ret.ToArray();
            to_ret.Clear();
        }
    }
```

This is how I did it ... I was thinking there is a more elegant way than this. :(

Comment: Got any code samples?

Comment: Don't think it's relevant. I have a Hashset<string> with 200.000 strings and I need to process them all. Processing all 200k at once is not an option. So, I need to take all of them in chunks of 1k (lets say) and do the processing. I know I can write my own method that loops through all 200k elements and save them into a 1k buffer then yield a result, but my question was if this can be done with something that .net already offers, something similar with CopyTo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't anything built-in.

However if you use the [MoreLinq](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) library (which is a useful thing to have around), then it has a [Batch](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/Batch.cs) operation which does what you want.

```
int batchSize = 1024;

foreach (var batch in myHashSet.Batch(batchSize))
{
    foreach (var item in batch)
    {
        ...
    } 
}
```